# Cordova Apple Watch plugin - WatchOS1 and WatchOS2 support

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, telerik, cordova-plugins, apple-watch

I'm developing a cordova app and using the [apple Watch plugin Apple watch by telerik](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/AppleWatch) After some days working with this plugin. (v0.6.0 Master). Now I need to release the app to the AppStore but xCode gave me next error when I try to upload to AppStore.

> ERROR ITMS-90636: "Invalid WatchKit Support. Starting June 1, 2016,
>   all new watchOS apps submitted to the App Store must be native apps
>   built with the watchOS 2 SDK or later. iPhone apps that introduce a
>   new WatchKit extension for watchOS 1.0 will no longer be accepted.
>   Learn more about developing for watchOS:
>   https://developer.apple.com/watchos/"

The problem is that the plugin have two branches, one for telerik with version "1.0.3" that fully support WatchOS2 and the master branch version "0.6.0" for all cordova projects that only support WatchOS1.

I would like to know if someone solved this issue taking code from the telerik branch or using other cordova plugin.

Comment: How did you resolve this? Aso any luck with WatchOS3/4?

Comment: Hello @socca1157 This was fixed. Just move to the branch "cordova-cli-watchos2" it's working good on wOS3, I still didn't test it on wOS4

Comment: Hi did the above solution work?